# SQL Server 2016 visual designer

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

For many years I created databases in MS Access. It was simple to create primary keys, unique indexes, and especially relationships, just by dragging a line from one table to the other. Is there anything similar available for SQL Server? TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Server Management Studio, there is tool named Database/Diagram Designer. You just need to create new diagram and then you can actually create tables and relations from there.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. I found the DatabaseDiagrams option in  SQL Server Management Studio, but when I select it and go to New Database Diagram, I get an empty list with Add Table buttons, even though there are tables in the database. And when I tried on a different database, I get index was outside the bounds of the array. Any clue what is wrong here? TIA

Comment: You have to right click the white space and add/show table. Also if my answer helped, mark it as accepted please :)